# Is there a standard Face Unlock icon / logo for Android?

Tags: user-interface, icons, biometrics, face, unlock

After scouring the internet, my own Pixel phone, and at least one app that uses face unlock, I have seen this icon used as a symbol for face unlock functionality. However I have not found a downloadable image to use for mockup purposes, either in Material Design UI kits or any other official source.

[Android face unlock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8nb4.png)

Is this a standard Android icon? Where can I download a legit SVG or PNG?

Comment: over a year later and I can't find a face unlock icon/logo still